# How to return only exact matches in Elasticsearch Python API

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

```
s = Search(using = client, index = . 
set_index).source(['metadata.Filename'])\
.query('match', Filename=(date))

total = s.count()

return total
```

I want to find the total number of instances where '20180511' appears in metadata.Filename in a particular index.

This query is returning a higher number of hits than I would have expected. The data format in metadata.Filename is GEOSCATCAT20180507_12+20180511_0900.V01.nc4. My date variable is in the format '20180511'.

I think the problem is match queries do the thing with scores, where they might return a hit even if it's not an exact match. I was wondering if you had any insight regarding this issue.

Comment: Can you provide an example of **bad** matching (such document, that shouldn't match your query, but that returned by Elastic)?
Also, it will be helpful if you provide your Elasticsearch schema (mapping/analyzers)

Comment: Assuming every file name follows this exact pattern you should use a tokenizer that will split this into tokens that you want to match on first. Checkout the pattern tokenizer in ES and either use it in your field analyzer(if FileName is text type) or search analyzer (if FileName is a keyword type).